# Accessing a cell in a data frame from user input within a function in R. Why won't the column acess letter work?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to take user input in a function to print the value from the cell in a data frame.

What I mean is if a user were to type in:

```
move("a3")
```

The result would be printing what is at "A3" of the data frame.

This is what I have so far but the "j" part isn't working and causing "NULL" to always be returned:

```
move <- function(start) { 
 j <- toupper(substr(start, 1, 1))
 k <- as.numeric(substr(start, 2, 2))
 vis_board$j[k]
}
```

And I would like it to do the following:

```
print(vis_board$A[3])
```

I hope this is enough information to understand my problem. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I think you want `vis_board[[j]][k]` - the `$` operator uses non-standard evaluation, so the function looks for a column literally called `j`, which doesn't exist. The `[[` operator doesn't have this problem / feature.

Comment: @AllanCameron Wow thank you so much for the quick response, that solved my problem straight away!! :D